# Generalized notion of the $p$-core for infinite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a finite group, and $p$ is a prime, the $p$-core of $G$, $O_p(G)$, is the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$.  The existence of $O_p(G)$ follows from the fact that the group-theoretic product of two finite normal $p$-subgroups is again a finite normal $p$-subgroup.

It seems to me that for infinite $G$, we can't define $O_p(G)$ in the same way, but I can't exactly see how, so I have two questions.

1. What problems arise from trying to define $O_p(G)$ to be the largest normal $p$-subgroup even when $G$ is infinite?  Any specific examples of infinite groups without a largest normal $p$-subgroup would be great.
2. Is there a generalized notion of the $p$-core of an infinite group?  If so, what properties does it possess that make it the proper generalization?  The wikipedia article mentions the solvable radical, $O_{\infty}(G)$, which is the largest solvable normal subgroup, but is this also only well-defined for finite $G$?

Comment: Why do you think you cannot define $O_p(G)$ for general groups? If $M$ and $N$ are normal $p$-subgroups of $G$, then $MN/(M \cap N) \cong M/(M \cap N) \times N/(M \cap N)$, so $MN$ is also a normal $p$-subgroup, and the union of a chain of normal $p$-subgroups is a normal $p$-subgroup. So doesn't $O_p(G)$ exist by Zorn' Lemma?

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks for the insight.  I follow your logic, but I'm intrigued by why every reference I find describing the $p$-core of a group requires the group to be finite.  The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_%28group%29#The_p-core) says there are generalizations to locally finite groups and profinite groups, but why would it say this if the generalization is just the exact same thing, and it even extends beyond these two cases?

Comment: I think whoever wrote that page was only thinking about finite groups and had not seriously considered the general case. The Fitting subgroup and the solvable radical do not generalize in this way, because the union of a chain of nilpotent or solvable groups is not necessarily nilpotent or solvable.